# Webview2 - Initialize CoreWebview2 before loading a webpage?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, iframe, webview2

I want to use the following code to load a page, and while it's loading use the FrameCreated event to load any iframes into the Iframelist as a CoreWebView2Frame object.

The problem is that the CoreWebView2 object needs to be initialized before the FrameCreated event handler can be created, but calling EnsureCoreWebView2Async before the browser has had time to start loading a page seems to make it hang. I can load a local dummy-page before, initialize the CoreWebview2 object, create the event handler, and then load the webpage I actually want to load, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant solution.

```
Dim IframeList As New List(Of CoreWebView2Frame)

Async Function LoadPage(link As String, pageMustcontain As String) As Task(Of Boolean)
    Dim Browser As New WebView2
    Await Browser.EnsureCoreWebView2Async()
    AddHandler Browser.CoreWebView2.FrameCreated, AddressOf FrameCreated
    Browser.Source = New Uri(link)
    Do
        Dim outerHTML As String = Await Browser.ExecuteScriptAsync("document.documentElement.outerHTML")
        If outerHTML.Contains(pageMustcontain) Then
            Return True
        End If
        Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)
        Application.DoEvents()
    Loop
End Function

Sub FrameCreated(sender As Object, e As CoreWebView2FrameCreatedEventArgs)
    IframeList.Add(e.Frame)
End Sub
```

Comment: `Await Browser.EnsureCoreWebView2Async()` is in the wrong place. To suggest where to add it, you need to specify the GUI platform you're using. If it's WinForms, in the `Load` event handler (make it async, of course), the `OnLoad()` override. If it's WPF, in the `Initialized` or `Loaded` handlers, etc.

Comment: @Jimi It's winforms, but this is meant to be part of a class that can be instantiated by multiple other forms/classes, which is why the browser is created on the spot. Are you suggesting that I use some global webview2 browser that is always loaded as the program runs and then this class simply uses it?

Comment: It doesn't matter. If you use a WebView2 Control to navigate to addresses provided by other classes (Forms or whatever else), initialize your class before any Form is initialized (in `Main()`) or a static (internal) method, in case you handle a singleton of that WebView2 object. Whatever the scenario is, add an async method that initializes a new instance of WebView (in case of a singleton, only if the instance doesn't exist yet) and awaits `EnsureCoreWebView2Async()` before you do anything else.

Comment: If the scenario is different, then describe what that is.

Comment: It would just be nice to only have the webview object loaded when it's being used. It's not used to visually display anything for the user, but simply runs for a few seconds in the background while it loads a website, reads some data from that website, and then it's done. It's sort of feels like starting your car in the morning when you're not leaving until noon for a 10 minute drive. Is there any reason not doing it as I described with the dummy-page? It seems better than having the webview object instantiated all the time.